# Sublime Text 3 support for Rust

Tags: editor, rust, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I am on Windows 7 and I would like to use Sublime Text 3 for editing Rust files. I am on Rust version 1.5.0.

I searched on the sublime site and found several packages listed on [sublime text rust packages](https://packagecontrol.io/search/rust). I downloaded the first package on that page - the one published by rust-lang. I followed the instructions on [the installation guide page](https://packagecontrol.io/installation). Afterwards I restarted sublime text.

However when I opened my .rs file, I did not see any syntax highlighting and every character was in white. I clicked on the View>Syntax menu, and I did not see Rust listed among the languages.

In folder AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages, I can see a file called Package Control.sublime-package. I assume that indicates that the package was downloaded at the least.

What could be wrong? Do I have the right expectation for syntax highlighting? Anybody had success with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you installed Package Control, just follow instruction on this page:
[Rust package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Rust%20Enhanced).

Install the Package Control package if you haven't got it yet. Package Control is the best way to install packages for Sublime Text. See http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation for instructions.

Open the palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) in Sublime Text and select Package Control: Install Package and then select Rust from the list. That's it.

P.S. Also, you can see another packages for sublime text for rust language on this page: http://areweideyet.com/#sublime